# Relative change between MAE and MSE

Tags: mean, model-evaluation

I want to make a statement about model prediction qualities, comparing several models based on MAE and MSE. Considering the following results:

[image: Model comparison]

Is it valid to say considering models 1 and 2:

- Model 1 outperforms two showing an improvement in MAE of 24% ((0.0792-0.1042)/0.1042).
- Model 1 has significantly fewer large errors due to much larger relative difference in MSE of 63% ((0.0188-0.0502)/0.0502)?

Should the relative difference in MAE and MSE between any two models be identical if they perform idnetical on "normal data" as well as considering outliers?

In general I am wondering on if and how to compare these two metrics with each other.
Is it possible to make an equal statement regarding R2, saying that although model 1 and 2 are not far apart by MAE, model 1 explains much more variance in the data?